# Is serial debugging possible for iOS Today Extensions?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, today-extension

I don't get any serial debug info from my print statements that are in my Today Extension swift class. Not sure of how to do this, as I'm only swiping right to bring up today extensions collection and scrolling to my apps' widget and letting it load. I've tried tapping on the body of the extension widget in an attempt to send serial debug info to debug console.

Using xCode 11 beta 7, MacOS 10.15 Catalina Beta 7, iPadOS 13.1 Beta.